# How to get google maps style from a embedded map

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to get the style of the google map used on this site

http://mundomaya.travel/#explora

so i can uses a similar one on my site.

I have learnt about styling maps here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?csw=1

but I cannot find their code.

any help would be appreciated.

---

ok I think they have just got TERRAIN set. where do they do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not using styled maps. They are using the "terrain" maptype (google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN). They initialize it that way in the initialize function in [this external javascript](http://mundomaya.travel/cache/template/mapa_flat-5132a872.js)

```
function initialize(maptype,scrollwheel){
  maptype=google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;
  var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(18.4,-90.3);
  var myOptions={
    zoom:5,center:latlng,
    mapTypeId:maptype,
    scrollwheel:scrollwheel, 
    panControl:false,
    streetViewControl:false,
    zoomControl:true,
    zoomControlOptions:{
      position:google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
    },
    mapTypeControl:true,
    mapTypeControlOptions:{
      position:google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM},
    };
    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
```